# Suggestions for rolling out a WebServer and Load Balancer with Juju Charms

Tags: apache2, juju, maas, nginx

I'm setting up a Maas/Juju Ubuntu 14.04 cluster and need some advice. The goal is to have HAProxy load balancing either Apache or Nginx that I can configure to host a set of php files that will be updated regularly.

I'm new to the infrastructure side of things but have been very impressed with Maas and Juju so far. I've taken a couple stabs at deploying the charms without success. Can anyone direct me to a resource that might be helpful to deploy this kind of setup? I haven't found a sample configuration that is similar to my concept so now I'm wondering if there's another, smarter, way.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet may be to try on a public cloud or in a local (lxc) environment to get a feel for how deploying and relating charms works. You can find the documentation on how to get started here: https://jujucharms.com/docs/#introduction

Once you have that set up you can try deploying the following:

```
juju deploy ghost
juju deploy haproxy
juju deploy mysql
juju add-relation ghost haproxy
juju add-relation ghost mysql
```

This environment is outlined in detail here: http://fromanegg.com/post/97035773367/juju-explain-it-to-me-like-im-5 which seems to follow similar a similar structure to what you want your environment to look like.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback hatch. I hadn't considered ghost since it looks more like a blogging site but it does segue to another architecture question I have. Any recommendations on what service I should try for deploying php files? Is it as simple as using nfs and configuring the web server to grab from it?